# Proof of a theorem about the Wiener index

Tags: graph-theory

I was studying the Wiener index of a certain class of graphs, hexagonal systems. I found this great survey of them, [Wiener Index of Hexagonal Systems](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~klavzar/preprints/Wiener-survey.pdf). On page 254, it is stated which subclasses have extremal Wiener indices:

\begin{align*}
\text{For any } h \ge 4 \text{ and } G \in \text{HC}_h \setminus \{ \text{L}_h, \text{H}_h \} \text{ it holds that } \text{W}(\text{H}_h) < \text{W}(G) < \text{W}(\text{L}_h)
\end{align*}

There are also references for this particular statement, yet those papers are unavailable to me and I'd like to see a proof of this theorem.
Could someone write/send me this proof, I am not interested in those articles, just this particular proof intrigues me.

Thanks.